# Create and save a text file with 'Save as' dialog in Electron

Tags: electron, fs

At the user's request, my Main process in Electron generates a (rather large) text file. The text file is temporarily stored in one of the app's subfolders (i.e. `"./temp/file.txt"`).

After the file is generated, I want to show a "Save As..." OS dialog to allow the user to save (copy?) said file into a directory outside my app folder.

I understand that you can display the "Save As..." dialog using `dialog.showSaveDialog()` and obtain a file destination path. But how can I copy the generated file to the destination path from the **Renderer** process?

Comment: Note that I don't want to transmit the file contents (200-300MB) using IPC because of the large file size.

Comment: You can send an Ipcmessage  to the main telling to copy from your temp to your choosen path destination.. No need to send data in the Ipc since the data are already on the file system in a temp folder

Comment: I'd suggest [fs-jetpack](https://github.com/szwacz/fs-jetpack) – it's `fs` but a little easier to use. So as @AlainBUFERNE suggests, send an `IPC` message to `main`, have it open the dialog and then do the copy (or move) of your "file.txt"